# ACF update fields

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a field with **Advanced Custom Fields** that is a number field to be used as a counter.

In `functions.php` i have created my shortcode function, and has this part:

```
<a href="https://myurl.com/wp-content/themes/child/dl.php?href=<?php echo esc_url( $link_url ); ?>&id=<?php echo $postid; ?>" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

And in the file `dl.php` i only have this:

```php
if ( $_GET['href'] && $_GET['id'] ) {
    $count = (int) get_field( 'download_counter', $_GET['id'] );
    $count++;
    update_field( 'download_counter', $count );
    header( 'Location: ' . $_GET['href'] );
} else {
    header( 'Location: https://myurl.com/' );
}
```

But I get "HTTP ERROR 500 Page not found!"

Before doing that, in my `functions.php` i put the same code and with every refresh of the page the counter worked.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work in the file `dl.php`?

Comment: This question is bout the plugin *ACF*, and is out of scope for this stack. For support on ACF, head over to https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: I think it's because the update_field function wouldn't be defined in a direct PHP file. I'd suggest switching back to the functions.php and wrapping the code in the init action and maybe adding another query parameter or changing the href parameter to something unique.

Comment: You could also try requiring wp-load.php from the root directory at the top of your script. That should load the site including ACF.

Comment: HTTP 500 is not "page not found" - it's "internal server error". The cause is likely as the others have suggested - you have not loaded WordPress in that file (as Rup suggests), and WordPress itself is not loading that code (as Toby suggests), so all of the WordPress/ACF functions you are attempting to use in that file are not available.

Comment: thank you all. Yes, the suggest of calling `wp-load.php` was the answer. 

my code work with this:
`if(!defined(ABSPATH)){
    $pagePath = explode('/wp-content/', dirname(__FILE__));
    include_once(str_replace('wp-content/' , '', $pagePath[0] . '/wp-load.php'));}`